# How can I refer a column by its index?

Tags: pyspark

I can use col("mycolumnname") function to get the column object.
Based on the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.col.html) the only possible parameter is the name of the column.

Is there any way to get the column object by its index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Let `n` be the index variable (integer).

```
df.select(df.columns[n]).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the expected result like this?

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
...
data = [
    (1, 'AC Milan'),
    (2, 'Real Madrid'),
    (3, 'Bayern Munich')
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'club'])
df.select(F.col('club')).show()
df.select(df['club']).show()
```