# How to compare two dataframes and pick only null value rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

i have two dataframes
df1=

```
columnA columnB columnC columnD
value1  value7  value13 value20
value2  value8  value14 value21
value3  value9  value15 value22
value4  value10 value16 value23
value5  value11 value17 value24
value6  null    null    value25
```

df2=

```
columnA columnB columnC columnD
value1  value7  value13 value20
value2  null    value14 value21
null    value9  value15 value22
value4  value10 value16 value23
value5  value11 value17 value24
value6  value12 value18 value25
```

i want to compare both the dataframe and i need to pick all rows which are null (missing values) after comparing both dataframes
my output dataframe should be like:
outputDF=

```
columnA columnB columnC columnD
value2  value8  value14 value21
value3  value9  value15 value22
value6  value12 value18 value25
```

how to achieve this using pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

Using isna() to select all rows with NaN under an entire DataFrame:

`df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]`

Using isnull() to select all rows with NaN under an entire DataFrame:

`df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]`

Comment: i want to find all the null rows from both the dataframes. presumably we dont have any primary key in both the columns

Comment: and also columns may vary in actual scenario like it may increase in both dataframes or decrease in both dataframes. need to handle this scenario.... wanted to know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are able to join on an id column... here I created one:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as psf

data1 = [ 
  ('value1','value7','value13','value20')
, ('value2','value8','value14','value21')
, ('value3','value9','value15','value22')
, ('value4','value10','value16','value23')
, ('value5','value11','value17','value24')
, ('value6',  None, None, 'value25')
]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, ['columnA', 'columnB', 'columnC', 'columnD'])

data2 = [ 
  ('value1','value7','value13','value20')
, ('value2', None,'value14','value21')
, (None, 'value9','value15','value22')
, ('value4','value10','value16','value23')
, ('value5','value11','value17','value24')
, ('value6','value12','value18','value25')
]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, ['columnA', 'columnB', 'columnC', 'columnD'])

df1=df1.withColumn('id', psf.monotonically_increasing_id())
df2=df2.withColumn('id', psf.monotonically_increasing_id())

df = df1.join(df2, how='inner', on='id').filter(
    (df1.columnA.isNull())
|   (df1.columnB.isNull())
|   (df1.columnC.isNull())
|   (df1.columnD.isNull())
|   (df2.columnA.isNull())
|   (df2.columnB.isNull())
|   (df2.columnC.isNull())
|   (df2.columnD.isNull())
).select(
    psf.coalesce(df1.columnA, df2.columnA).alias('ColumnA')
,   psf.coalesce(df1.columnB, df2.columnB).alias('ColumnB')
,   psf.coalesce(df1.columnC, df2.columnC).alias('ColumnC')
,   psf.coalesce(df1.columnD, df2.columnD).alias('ColumnD')
).show()
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.... how to make it generic code? like in future i might have more columns or less columns accordingly

Comment: and also column names might vary ,,,,, so needed to handle this scenario. wanted help on like how to achieve this...

Comment: @karthik if you don't have a primary key then you'll need to add one your self if you want rows to align across two tables

Comment: @karthik you can reference columns by position in the dataframe so you don't know column names at runtime see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69628674/how-can-i-refer-a-column-by-its-index

Comment: is it possible to make these columns generic? because we wont be sure of the columns coming in

Comment: @karthik see comment above. Suggested that you reference columns by position to make them generic.